# how can I use selenium and web drive in this case

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Hello I am new in python and would like to use selenium's webdriver, I would like to automate the login and password on an the page, could someone help me, I have searched a lot, but what I found didn't help me.

oh yes I forgot, this is my first post on tack overflow. :)
and I'm a new coder .

this is th e HTML code, ho I want to control :

```
<input label="email" placeholder="your@email.com" 
       type="email" aria-labelledby="email" 
       data-lpignore="false" 
       class="TextInputWrapper-sc-1tsvy2y-0 gJpMOv" 
       value=">
<input label="password" placeholder="password" 
       type="password" aria-labelledby="password" 
       data-lpignore="false" class="TextInputWrapper-sc-1tsvy2y-0 gJpMOv" 
       value="">
 <a class="login__forgot-password" href="#/reset-password">Forgot your password?</a>
 <div class="login__form__button login__form__button--spaced">
     <button width="100%" class="ButtonWrapper-sc-1vti96x-0 eQYxT">
         <div class="ButtonContent-sc-1vti96x-1 bkKPpq">
            Login to xxx
         </div>
     </button>
 </div>
```

and here is my python code

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("path/chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get("https://......")
    elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("TextInputWrapper-sc-1tsvy2y-0 gJpMOv")
    elem.clear()
    elem.send_keys("xxxxxxx@gmail.com")
    elem.click()
```

if anyone could help me please, thanks

Answer (score 0):

here is the code (replace `***` with your data):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

login = {
    "username" : "***",
    "password" : "***"
}

driver = webdriver.***

driver.get("***")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("***").send_keys(login["username"]) # username
driver.find_element_by_xpath("***").send_keys(login["password"]) # password
driver.find_element_by_xpath("***").click()                      # submit
```

I don't know full source code, so you need to get full xpath of element by clicking `Copy > XPath` when inspecting the element.

Comment: You are welcome, @helmichiha. Please accept this answer if I answered your question completely. Accepting answer tells community that it helped you and question is closed. If you need more help edit this question or create a new one.